# How to get valid OAuth token from OWIN external authentication middleware?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth, owin

I'm developing middleware for OWIN application. Authentication is done via external providers, such as Facebook and Google.

Everything is done more or less by the book (I mean examples in the Internet), but I have one special requirement — link external user to a local user, and issue respective bearer token.

And I just cannot get how I can achieve that. Here is the example code:

```
var identity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, Options.SignInAsAuthenticationType);

identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName, null, Options.AuthenticationType));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.name));

identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AuthorizationLevel", user.AuthorizationLevel.ToString()));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ContactId", user.ContactId.ToString()));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ImpersonateAs", user.ImpersonateAs.ToString()));

Context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    IsPersistent = false 
}, identity);
```

So local user is authenticated. But via cookie I assume. Is it possible somehow turn that cookie into normal bearer token using `Context.Authentication` or any other approach?

Many thanks in advance for any clue how it could be possibly done.